# Surely there Should be a more clean way of writing this Flask route code

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, simplify

I want to edit my contacts in my web footer section and I have made this:
In my Admin page I made it so I can fill out a form with 4 inputs for each contact `form.contact1 form.contact2 form.contact3 form.contact4`... at the same time I made a `Contacts` Model containing the `content` column.

---

### My route code:

```
@app.route('/admin/media-kontaktai', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def media_contacts():
    form = MediaContactsForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        rows = db.session.query(func.count(Contacts.id)).scalar()
        for x in range(1, rows+1):
            erace_contact = Contacts.query.get(x)
            db.session.delete(erace_contact)
            db.session.commit()
        if form.contact1.data:
            contact = Contacts(content=form.contact1.data)
            db.session.add(contact)
            db.session.commit()
        if form.contact2.data:
            contact = Contacts(content=form.contact2.data)
            db.session.add(contact)
            db.session.commit()
        if form.contact3.data:
            contact = Contacts(content=form.contact3.data)
            db.session.add(contact)
            db.session.commit()
        if form.contact4.data:
            contact = Contacts(content=form.contact4.data)
            db.session.add(contact)
            db.session.commit()
        flash('Informacija atnaujinta!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('media_contacts'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        contact1 = Contacts.query.get(1)
        form.contact1.data = contact1.content
        contact2 = Contacts.query.get(2)
        form.contact2.data = contact2.content
        contact3 = Contacts.query.get(3)
        form.contact3.data = contact3.content
        contact4 = Contacts.query.get(4)
        form.contact4.data = contact4.content
    contacts = Contacts.query.all()
    return  render_template('a-media-kontaktai.html', title='Media ir kontaktai', form=form, contacts=contacts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested.  See if it works:

```
for i in range (1,5):
    if form['contact' + str(i)].data:
        contact = Contacts(content=form['contact' + str(i)].data)
        db.session.add(contact)
        db.session.commit()
```

Comment: `form` may treat attribute lookup and indexing interchangably, assuming it doesn't you could also do `getattr(form, 'contact'+i)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but it should work or at least put you on to the right path on how to condense it even further.

```
@app.route('/admin/media-kontaktai', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def media_contacts():
    form = MediaContactsForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            try:
                # You can just delete all records in one go instead of 
                # wasting time iterating and checking lengths
                db.session.query(Contacts).delete()
                db.session.commit()
            except:
                db.session.rollback()
            
            # I am iterating fields in the form that have data 
            # so we don't need multiple if statements
            for field in [field for field in form if field.data]:
                contact = Contacts(content=field.data)
                db.session.add(contact)
                db.session.commit()
            
            flash('Informacija atnaujinta!', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('media_contacts'))
    
    else:
        for field, index in enumerate(form):
            for contact in Contacts.query.all():
                field.data = contact.content
    
    contacts = Contacts.query.all()
    return  render_template('a-media-kontaktai.html', title='Media ir kontaktai', form=form, contacts=contacts)
```

Comment: WOAAAAH THANKS A LOT, this helped me a lot and I learned more things too!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Be sure to mark as answer when you can, thank you.